# select2 angular not able to load thousands of rec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select2

I have used select2 angular for autocomplete tagging it working nice but if I load more than 4000 records it stops executing and block the web page.

Any way to fix this issue for thousands of record ?

My code

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/master/src/select2.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    No Results Tag: {{ noResultsTag }}
    <br />
    <select style="width: 400px;" ui-select2="select2Options" multiple ng-model="selectedTags">
        <option ng-repeat="tag in tags" value="{{tag.id}}">{{tag.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    Tags: 
    <pre>
        {{ tags | json }}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.select2']);

function MyCtrl($scope, $compile, $timeout) {
    $scope.noResultsTag = null;
    $scope.tags = [
        {id: 0, name: "Zero"},
        {id: 1, name: "One"},
        {id: 2, name: "Two"}, 
        {id: 3, name: "Three"}, 
        {id: 4, name: "Four"}, 
    ];
    $scope.select2Options = {
        formatNoMatches: function(term) {
            console.log("Term: " + term);
            var message = '<a ng-click="addTag()">Add tag:"' + term + '"</a>';
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.noResultsTag = term;
                });
            }
            return message;
        }
    };

    $scope.addTag = function() {
        $scope.tags.push({
            id: $scope.tags.length,
            name: $scope.noResultsTag
        });
    };

    $scope.$watch('noResultsTag', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var noResultsLink = $('.select2-no-results');
                console.log(noResultsLink.contents());
                $compile(noResultsLink.contents())($scope);
            });
        }
    }, true);
}
```

this example is running nice issue is with thousands of records.
 To test http://jsfiddle.net/jld42/4/

Comment: Have you tried using oData api's. This way you won't have to get everything all at once.

Comment: It is a bit slow but it seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/2tjrojnf/

Comment: yeah it works quite slow up to 3000 records but it gets crash after 6000 records well now I am trying domething else

Comment: do let us know if you got around to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem a while ago. The solution in our case was to load the data with an AJAX call and paginate the results. This ensures the plugin won't freeze the whole page and the data get's loaded at a nice pace.

Take a look at the official documentation here: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax